# unrecognized option item under sylius_sales.classes

Tags: symfony, sylius

I'm trying to install sylius and I get this error when clearing cache after composer update

unrecognized option item under sylius_sales.classes

Sorry - I mean sylius sandbox

Comment: According to Packagist, sylius/sylius has been installed 12 times in total. You probably should look for some support from the developer if you have any problem with it.

Comment: Sorry - I mean sylius sandbox

Answer (score 0):

You should not update the vendors. They are locked in composer.lock file on purpose, to not break on changes. And there are some BC Break changes in most of bundles. The reason is that sandbox is not developed anymore, everything was moved to https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius.

The reason behind this error - option was renamed to `order_item`.